# Python - Update tuple string element error

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, tuples

I have a dataframe where every row is a list of tuples , i.e.: `tuple = (word, pos_tag)`. In each row, I want to change the `word` of some tuples by marking it and then update the tuple with the marked word. For example:

**Initial dataframe row :**

```
[('This', 'DET'), ('is', 'VERB'), ('an', 'DET'), ('example', 'NOUN'), ('text', 'NOUN'), ('that', 'DET'), ('I', 'PRON'), ('use', 'VERB'), ('in', 'ADP'), ('order', 'NOUN'), ('to', 'PART'), ('get', 'VERB'), ('an', 'DET'), ('answer', 'NOUN')]
```

**Updated words :**

```
updated_word : <IN>example</IN>
updated_word  : <TAR>answer</TAR>
```

**Desired output :**

```
[('This', 'DET'), ('is', 'VERB'), ('an', 'DET'), ('<IN>example</IN>', 'NOUN'), ('text', 'NOUN'), ('that', 'DET'), ('I', 'PRON'), ('use', 'VERB'), ('in', 'ADP'), ('order', 'NOUN'), ('to', 'PART'), ('get', 'VERB'), ('an', 'DET'), ('<TAR>answer</TAR>', 'NOUN')]
```

But I get an error that `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`. Can someone help? Here's the code :

```python
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    doc = nlp(row['title'])
    pos_tags = [(token.text, token.pos_) for token in doc if not token.pos_ == "PUNCT"]

    for position, tuple in enumerate(pos_tags, start=1):
        word = tuple[0]
        spacy_pos_tag = tuple[1]
        word = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', word)
        for col in cols:
            if position in row[col]:
                word = f'<{col.upper()}>{word}</{col.upper()}>'
            else:
                continue
            tuple = tuple(word, spacy_pos_tag)
            print(tuple)


 >>>>   Traceback (most recent call last):
 >>>>   tuple = tuple(word, spacy_pos_tag)
 >>>>   TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

**Updated question**

I have replaced `tuple` with `tuple_` as suggested, but I still can't get back the desired output which is a list of tuples in every row. Can someone help how to update the dataframe rows? Here's the updated code :

```python
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    doc = nlp(row['title'])
    pos_tags = [(token.text, token.pos_) for token in doc if not token.pos_ == "PUNCT"]
    # print(idx, "tokens, pos : ", pos_tags, "\n")

    for position, tuple_ in enumerate(pos_tags, start=1):
        word = tuple_[0]
        spacy_pos_tag = tuple_[1]
        word = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', word)
        for col in cols:
            if position in row[col]:
                word = f'<{col.upper()}>{word}</{col.upper()}>'
            else:
                continue
            tuple_ = (word, spacy_pos_tag)
        pos_tags.append(' '.join(position, tuple_))
    # pos_tags.append(' '.join(tuple_))
    print(idx, "tokens, pos : ", pos_tags, "\n")
    
    
>>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
>>>> pos_tag(df=df_matched)
>>>> pos_tags.append(' '.join(position, tuple_))
>>>> TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `tuple` as a variable name, as it is a built-in python type name. Try the following instead:

```
    for position, tuple_ in enumerate(pos_tags, start=1):
        word = tuple_[0]
        spacy_pos_tag = tuple_[1]
        word = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', word)
        for col in cols:
            if position in row[col]:
                word = f'<{col.upper()}>{word}</{col.upper()}>'
            else:
                continue

            tuple_ = (word, spacy_pos_tag)
            print(tuple_)
```

Comment: Ok I don't have this error now, but I'm not getting back the desired output which is a list of tuples. Instead, I am getting each tuple separately

Comment: @joasa Please consider tlentali's answer on how to implement this properly in pandas. this answer just fixes your main issue

Comment: No @tlentali's answer doesn't help, because in each row it's random which word will be replaced. Your answer is the one that helps, although I would like to know how I will have a list of tuples in each row, as in the desired output of my question

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "tuple" as name of a variable. It's a type name

Comment: Your answer is a duplicate answer.